# I renamed ViewController.swift and now nothing appears in the Assistant editor in Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift

I renamed ViewController.swift to PickViewController.swift and now it doesn't appear in the Assistant editor.

I guess this is because PickViewController.swift is no longer related to the image in Main.storyboard.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: you change name through refactor ?

Comment: @rachelvsamuel please upvote my answer if it helped :) cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XCode 11, you can use `option(alt) + click` on the file (in your case `PickViewController.swift`) that you want to view in assistant editor.

Answer (score 1):

You should rename the class from the identity inspector to `PickViewController` as well:

[image]

**Note that** you can use refactor option to make the process more automated by command + click on the controller's name and select **rename**:

[image]

Or from the menu:

[image]

Comment: How do I reactor this? Where do I click?